# how can I get a div to remain fixed and move div's either side away on hover

Tags: php, css

I have a PHP query that looks up names and details of volunteer staff. These are displayed in row left to right as thumbnail images. On hover they ease out using css to show details.

```
<?php while($fetch = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $Name =str_replace('-',' ',$fetch['Name']);
  $About =str_replace('-',' ',$fetch['About']);
  $id = $fetch['id'];
  $Thumb = $fetch['Thumbnail'];
  $class++;
  if ($class == $max) { 
    $class =0;  
  }
  if ($class > 5) {
    $id = ("thumbnail_r"); //changes to id so the thumb floats right
  }
  else if($class < 6) {
    $id = ("thumbnail_l");//changes to id so the thumb floats left
  }
?>
<div id="thumb_w"><p><?php echo '<img src="staff/'.$Thumb.'" alt="'.$Name.'" width="100px" height="100px" id="'.$id.'"/>';?>
  <?php echo $Name?>
  <?php echo $About?></p>
</div>
<?php
}
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

**With the css.**

```
#thumb_w{
  border: 6px inset #0c3af0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 29px -4px rgba(100,90,232,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 29px -4px rgba(100,90,232,1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 29px -4px rgba(100,90,232,1);
  height: 111px;    
  width: 111px;
  margin: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari */
  transition: width 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: rgb(160, 156, 250);
  float: left;
}
#thumb{
  z-index:1;
  border: 6px inset #0c3af0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 29px -4px rgba(100,90,232,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 29px -4px rgba(100,90,232,1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 29px -4px rgba(100,90,232,1);
  transition:1.5s ease-in-out;
  height: 121px;        
}
#thumb_w:hover {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 111px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;    
  max-height: 111px;
}

img#thumbnail{
  max-width: 108px;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 99px;
  max-height: 120px;
}
#thumbnail_l{
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
#thumbnail_r{
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

Is there a way of making the thumbnail you hover on to remain fixed and all the other thumbnails slide away. It does not have to be css, this is just what I am use to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use jQuery mouseenter and mouseleave method.

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

Or you can use hover method

```
$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

this is the reference

- https://api.jquery.com/hover/
- http://api.jquery.com/on/